# Is there any PHP script for mining monero on webserver?

Tags: mining

I have seen may tutorials and links for webmining on client, Is there any php based miner for server?

Comment: I don't know about PHP, but there is some project with nodejs, for mining on server. for example: https://github.com/cazala/coin-hive

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the sever to run PHP code then you can just use a cpu or gpu monero miner anyway which are much faster and readily available for download and use.

As far as mining on a web client (not clear if that is what you're asking about):

Web based client side miners (such as javascript miners) use the web browsers or video streamers etc of the client machine to perform mining.

It is being done with platforms like [coinhive](https://www.coinhive.com/) as a monitization strategy (ethically questionable imo) where one would **alert** the user about it and **ask for permission**
but it is usually done by malware illegally in what is called [Cryptohjacking](https://bitcoinwiki.co/cryptojacking-some-websites-are-using-your-cpu-to-mine-monero/). Essentially this is taking advantage of people's computers for ones own personal gain without any regard for those people or their devices

Comment: No no u got me wrong i want to leverage the servers resources. I want to run miner on server which purely coded in php.

Comment: Then why do you use the phrase 'webmining on client' ? And are you saying you DO NOT have access to the server directly? only the ability to code a function on the server such as using an AWS Lambda function or Google Apps Engine Cloud function ?